# Boundary layer momentum equation

Tags: fluid-mechanics, cfd

[image]

How does the author get that formula(d alpha formula) using the momentum equation . The book here is Mechanics and thermodynamics of propulsion by Philip Hill and Carl Peterson.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It involves simple differentiation operation to get there.

We have $\frac{dP}{\rho} = -UdU$ and $\frac{dP}{\rho} = -udu$. These equations can be re-organised as
$$\frac{-dP}{\rho U} = dU, ~\frac{-dP}{\rho u} = du$$
Given, $\alpha = \frac{u}{U}$. Differentiate this relation on both sides, we get
$$d\alpha = \frac{du}{U} - \frac{u}{U^2}dU$$
Now, substitute the expressions for $du$ and $dU$ in the above, we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
 d\alpha &= &\frac{1}{U}\frac{-dP}{\rho u} - \frac{u}{U^2}\frac{-dP}{\rho U}\\
&= &-\frac{1}{U^2}\frac{U}{u}\frac{dP}{\rho} + \frac{1}{U^2} 
\frac{u}{U}\frac{dP}{\rho} \\
&= &-\frac{1}{U^2}\frac{1}{\alpha}\frac{dP}{\rho} + \frac{1}{U^2} \alpha\frac{dP}{\rho} \\
&= & \frac{dP}{\rho U^2}\left(\alpha - \frac{1}{\alpha}\right)\\
&= & \frac{dP}{\rho U^2}\left(\frac{\alpha^2 - 1}{\alpha}\right)
\end{eqnarray*}

Hope this answers!

Comment: Thank you Krishna .. :)